# Vector space over finite field, connecting two formulae.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The two formalae:

For a linear transformation $\phi$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$:
$$
  \operatorname{dim}(V) = \operatorname{dim}(ker(\phi)) + \operatorname{dim}(im(\phi)).  \qquad (1)
$$
And for a group homomorphism $\psi: G \to G'$ of finite groups:
$$
  |G| = |ker(\psi)| \cdot |im(\psi)|.  \qquad (2)
$$
Now the following exercise (from Artin, Algebra, page. 145)

When the field is one of the fields $\mathbb F_p$, finite dimensional vector spaces have finitely many elements. In this case, formula (1) and formala (2) both apply. Reconcile them.

Let $\phi$ be a linear transformation, I guess the only connection is
$$
  p^{\operatorname{dim}(V)} = |V| 
                            = |ker(\phi)| \cdot |im(\phi)| 
                            = p^{\operatorname{dim}{ker(\phi)}} p^{\operatorname{dim}{im(\phi)}} 
$$
and
$$
  |ker(\phi)| = p^{\operatorname{dim}{ker(\phi)}} \qquad
   |im(\phi)| = p^{\operatorname{dim}{im(\phi)}}.
$$
These seem quite obvious, or are there any other connections?

Comment: Do you see how to deduce (2) from (1), and vice versa? Then you have solved the exercise.

Comment: Ok, I got tired! I've Artin's book open in page 145 in front of my nose and I can't find that exercise. As there are several sets of exercises in the following pages (all of them beginning with exercise number 1...oh, authors: you drive me nuts some times!), would you *please* be so kind as to be more specific what exercise *exactly* is that?

Comment: It exercise number 7 from chapter 4, paragraph 1 (The Dimension Formula). I have the 1991 edition of the book (guess it is the first edition).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the comment, guess I have a proof, it is based on the fact that for every vector space over a finite field $\mathbb F_p$ with $p$ prime, $|V| = p^n$, where $n = \operatorname{dim}(V)$.

i) Suppose $|V| = |ker(\phi)| \cdot |im(\phi)|$ holds. As $ker \phi$ and $im \phi$ are subspaces over the same base field, it muss hold that
$$
  |ker \phi| = p^k \qquad |im \phi| = p^l
$$
where $k$ and $l$ are the dimensions of these spaces. And because of the supposition,
$$
 p^n = |V| = |ker(\phi)| \cdot |im(\phi)|
$$
it could just hold that
$$
 |ker \phi| = p^{n-q} \qquad |im \phi| = p^{q}.
$$
From this it follows by unique prime factorisation, that $k = n-q$ and $l = q$, which says $k + l = n$.

ii) Other direction, suppose
$$
  \operatorname{dim}(V) = \operatorname{dim}(ker(\phi)) + \operatorname{dim}(im(\phi))
$$
holds. Then with $n = \operatorname{dim}(V)$
$$
 |V| = p^n = p^{\operatorname{dim}(ker(\phi)) + \operatorname{dim}(im(\phi))}
           = p^{\operatorname{dim}(ker(\phi))} \cdot p^{\operatorname{dim}
(im(\phi))}
           = |ker \phi| \cdot |im \phi|
$$
again by using the property that the kernel and images are subspaces, and so they have $p^{\operatorname{dim}(ker(\phi))},p^{\operatorname{dim}(im(\phi))}$
elements.

Right?

Comment: It looks okay overall, but I don't understand the bit in (i) that says, "because of the supposition...it could just hold that...". Before that, you said "it must hold that $|\text{ker}\varphi|=p^k$ and $|\text{img}\varphi|=p^l$." Why not just write $p^n=p^kp^l=p^{k+l}$ and take $\log_p$ of both sides?